# Which Live CD should I use to repair my ext4 partition on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook, ext4

I have been affected by [an ext4 unmountable problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1601810).

The suggested solution is to run `e2fsck` in a live CD. Ubuntu can't be used because it periodically tries to mount the partition (/dev/sda3 in my case) preventing e2fsck from running.  In other words, in order to recover Ubuntu, I want to try using a non-Ubuntu Live CD.

Other people have had success with Slax. But it doesn't work on MacBook.

What live CDs will work on my MacBook?

Comment: I suggest you move this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/, where you will probably get much better answers.

Answer (score 3):

Solved with Parted Magic live CD and running `e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda3`